# Make image fill remaining vertical height without using float

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
div {box-sizing: border-box; color: white;}

img {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%;}

h2 {float: left; display: block; padding-bottom: 10px; font: 14px sans-serif; background-color: red; width: 100%; margin: 0px;}

div.left {background-color: black; border-right:solid 5px white; float: left; width: 66.66%; padding: 10px; overflow: auto; }
div.right {background-color: green; border-left:solid 5px white; float: right; width: 33.33%; padding: 10px; overflow: auto;}
</style>

<div class="container" style="width: 100%; background-color: red;">
    
    <div class="left" aspect="2">
         <h2>this a header</h2>
        
         <img src="http://imagesofrmnp.com/images/300/Longs-Illuminated.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
        

    </div>
    
    <div class="right" aspect="1">
        <h2>this a header</h2>
         
        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2049807/school-house_1x.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
        
    </div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
     
    
    function FixAspect()
    {
        $("div[aspect]").css("height", function() { return Math.round(this.getBoundingClientRect().width / $(this).attr("aspect")); });
    }
    
    setInterval(FixAspect, 50);
</script>
```

You can see that by using height 100% the image overflows because the header takes a part of those 100%. So basically it has to fill the remaining space.

I know i can calculate how much space the header takes with js, but a css solution would be better.

I tried floating the header but it didn't help.

Note that the aspect ratio of the image does not have to be preserved.

Comment: Can you specify if the image will be portrait or landscape? (you may not know ahead of time...)

Comment: it doesn't matter, the image aspect ratio does not have to be preserved. What matters is the div aspect ratio, which is fixed already.

Comment: Do you know anything about the header over the image, can we assume one line or a fixed height?

Comment: No the header has variable height. The only solution i can think of is using jquery to calculate the image height by subtracting the container height from the header height.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%; background-color: red;">

    <div class="left" aspect="2">
    </div>

    <div class="right" aspect="1">
        <h2>this a test header</h2>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {box-sizing: border-box; color: white;}

        img {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}

        div.left {background-color: black; border-right:solid 10px orange; float: left; width: 66.6666%;  }
        div.right {background-color: green; border-left:solid 10px orange; float: right; width: 33.3333%;  overflow: hidden;}
        div.right{

            background-image: url("http://promundoglobal.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/images.jpg");
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Loeapap1/12/

Comment: i cant use background image, because the image will be a <svg>